# how to pass to ppatcher activity under any condition in main activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, smali

hi iam trying to bypass login activity from an app with firebase database i think if i manage to edit main activity to get to ppatcher activity even if i didn't get auth i can use this app for self interest
would that be a problem ?

note i didn't know much about java or smali but iam trying so if any of those codes editing will make a problem with firebase please let me know and what line should i edit prefer in smali so it would be a fast build

```
.class Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "MainActivity.java"

# interfaces
.implements Lcom/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener;


# annotations
.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/EnclosingMethod;
    value = Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->onDataChange(Lcom/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot;)V
.end annotation

.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/InnerClass;
    accessFlags = 0x0
    name = null
.end annotation


# instance fields
.field final synthetic this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

.field final synthetic val$aa:Ljava/lang/Long;

.field final synthetic val$refff:Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

.field final synthetic val$reffff:Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

.field final synthetic val$uidf:Ljava/lang/String;


# direct methods
.method constructor <init>(Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;Ljava/lang/Long;Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;)V
    .locals 0

    .line 300
    iput-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iput-object p2, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$aa:Ljava/lang/Long;

    iput-object p3, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$refff:Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    iput-object p4, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$uidf:Ljava/lang/String;

    iput-object p5, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$reffff:Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method

.method private static rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    .locals 5

    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-direct {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Ljava/lang/String;->toCharArray()[C

    move-result-object v2

    const/4 v0, 0x0

    :goto_0
    array-length v3, v2

    if-ge v0, v3, :cond_0

    rem-int/lit8 v3, v0, 0x4

    packed-switch v3, :pswitch_data_0

    aget-char v3, v2, v0

    xor-int/lit8 v3, v3, -0x1

    int-to-char v3, v3

    invoke-virtual {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    :goto_1
    add-int/lit8 v0, v0, 0x1

    goto :goto_0

    :pswitch_0
    aget-char v3, v2, v0

    const v4, 0x3a080

    xor-int/2addr v3, v4

    int-to-char v3, v3

    invoke-virtual {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    goto :goto_1

    :pswitch_1
    aget-char v3, v2, v0

    const v4, 0x583acffd

    xor-int/2addr v3, v4

    int-to-char v3, v3

    invoke-virtual {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    goto :goto_1

    :pswitch_2
    aget-char v3, v2, v0

    const v4, -0x23541b8c

    xor-int/2addr v3, v4

    int-to-char v3, v3

    invoke-virtual {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    goto :goto_1

    :cond_0
    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    return-object v0

    nop

    :pswitch_data_0
    .packed-switch 0x0
        :pswitch_0
        :pswitch_1
        :pswitch_2
    .end packed-switch
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public onCancelled(Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError;)V
    .locals 3

    .line 335
    iget-object v0, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object v0, v0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object v0, v0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    const-string v1, "\ua0c5\ucf8f\ue406\uff90\ua0f2\ucfdd\ue445\uffcf\ua0b1"

    invoke-static {v1}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    const/4 v2, 0x0

    invoke-static {v0, v1, v2}, Les/dmoral/toasty/Toasty;->error(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

    .line 336
    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError;->toException()Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseException;

    move-result-object p1

    const-string v0, "\ua0cd\ucf9c\ue41d\uff91\ua0c1\ucf9e\ue400\uff96\ua0f6\ucf94\ue400\uff86"

    invoke-static {v0}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    const-string v1, "\ua0ef\ucf93\ue437\uff9e\ua0ee\ucf9e\ue411\uff93\ua0ec\ucf98\ue410"

    invoke-static {v1}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v0, v1, p1}, Landroid/util/Log;->w(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)I

    return-void
.end method

.method public onDataChange(Lcom/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot;)V
    .locals 7

    .line 303
    const-class v0, Ljava/lang/String;

    invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot;->getValue(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object p1

    check-cast p1, Ljava/lang/String;

    const-string v0, "\ua0b2\ucfcd\ue444"

    invoke-static {v0}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    const-string v1, "\ua0cc\ucf92\ue413\uff96\ua0ee"

    invoke-static {v1}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    const/4 v2, 0x0

    if-eqz p1, :cond_1

    .line 304
    invoke-static {}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->access$100()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->contains(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z

    move-result v3

    if-eqz v3, :cond_1

    .line 305
    new-instance p1, Ljava/util/Date;

    invoke-direct {p1}, Ljava/util/Date;-><init>()V

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Ljava/util/Date;->getTime()J

    move-result-wide v3

    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$aa:Ljava/lang/Long;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Ljava/lang/Long;->longValue()J

    move-result-wide v5

    cmp-long p1, v3, v5

    if-gez p1, :cond_0

    .line 306
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    new-instance v3, Landroid/content/Intent;

    iget-object v4, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object v4, v4, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object v4, v4, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    const-class v5, Lsika/pubg/mobile/PPatcher;

    invoke-direct {v3, v4, v5}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->startActivity(Landroid/content/Intent;)V

    .line 307
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    invoke-virtual {p1, v1, v2}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->getSharedPreferences(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-interface {p1}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;->edit()Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-interface {p1, v1, v0}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->putString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-interface {p1}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->apply()V

    .line 309
    :cond_0
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->login:Landroid/widget/Button;

    invoke-virtual {p1, v2}, Landroid/widget/Button;->setClickable(Z)V

    .line 310
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->mProgressDialog:Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;->dismiss()V

    goto/16 :goto_0

    :cond_1
    if-nez p1, :cond_4

    .line 312
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$refff:Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    iget-object v3, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$uidf:Ljava/lang/String;

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;->child(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    move-result-object p1

    const-string v3, "\ua0d5\ucfa8\ue43d\uffbb"

    invoke-static {v3}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;->child(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-static {}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->access$100()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;->setValue(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task;

    .line 313
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$reffff:Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    iget-object v3, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$uidf:Ljava/lang/String;

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;->child(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    move-result-object p1

    const-string v3, "\ua0f4\ucf94\ue419\uff9a"

    invoke-static {v3}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;->child(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;

    move-result-object p1

    const-string v3, "\ua0b1\ucfcf\ue447"

    invoke-static {v3}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference;->setValue(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task;

    .line 314
    invoke-static {}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->access$100()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object p1

    if-eqz p1, :cond_3

    .line 315
    invoke-static {}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->access$100()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->contains(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z

    move-result p1

    if-eqz p1, :cond_3

    .line 316
    new-instance p1, Ljava/util/Date;

    invoke-direct {p1}, Ljava/util/Date;-><init>()V

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Ljava/util/Date;->getTime()J

    move-result-wide v3

    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->val$aa:Ljava/lang/Long;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Ljava/lang/Long;->longValue()J

    move-result-wide v5

    cmp-long p1, v3, v5

    if-gez p1, :cond_2

    .line 317
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    new-instance v3, Landroid/content/Intent;

    iget-object v4, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object v4, v4, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object v4, v4, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    const-class v5, Lsika/pubg/mobile/PPatcher;

    invoke-direct {v3, v4, v5}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V

    invoke-virtual {p1, v3}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->startActivity(Landroid/content/Intent;)V

    .line 318
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    invoke-virtual {p1, v1, v2}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->getSharedPreferences(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-interface {p1}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;->edit()Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-interface {p1, v1, v0}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->putString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-interface {p1}, Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;->apply()V

    .line 320
    :cond_2
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->login:Landroid/widget/Button;

    invoke-virtual {p1, v2}, Landroid/widget/Button;->setClickable(Z)V

    .line 321
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->mProgressDialog:Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;->dismiss()V

    goto :goto_0

    .line 323
    :cond_3
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->mProgressDialog:Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;->dismiss()V

    .line 324
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    const-string v0, "\ua0d3\ucf92\ue419\uff9a\ua0a0\ucfb8\ue406\uff8d\ua0ef\ucf8f\ue454\uffb0\ua0e3\ucf9e\ue401\uff8d\ua0f2\ucf98\ue410\uffdf\ua0c3\ucf92\ue401\uff93\ua0e4\ucfda\ue400\uffdf\ua0cc\ucf92\ue413\uff96\ua0ee"

    invoke-static {v0}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-static {p1, v0, v2}, Les/dmoral/toasty/Toasty;->error(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

    goto :goto_0

    .line 327
    :cond_4
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;->mProgressDialog:Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Lsika/antiban/ui/progress/login;->dismiss()V

    .line 328
    iget-object p1, p0, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->this$2:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1;->this$1:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;

    iget-object p1, p1, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3;->this$0:Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity;

    const-string v0, "\ua0d5\ucf93\ue41f\uff91\ua0ef\ucf8a\ue41a\uffdf\ua0c4\ucf98\ue402\uff96\ua0e3\ucf98\ue454\uffc5\ua0a0\ucfbe\ue41b\uff91\ua0f4\ucf9c\ue417\uff8b\ua0a0\ucfbc\ue404\uff8f\ua0a0\ucfbc\ue410\uff92\ua0e9\ucf93\ue454"

    invoke-static {v0}, Lsika/pubg/mobile/MainActivity$3$1$3;->rm(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;->intern()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-static {p1, v0, v2}, Les/dmoral/toasty/Toasty;->error(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object p1

    invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

    :goto_0
    return-void
.end method
```

Comment: what did you try in there?